# How to select text and value from the dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html

How to select text and value from the dropdown using javascript. I thought using text I will get the selected dropdown text.  for value, it's working fine.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").text;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
    <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="4">Banana</option>
  </select>


  <p>Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
```

Something like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = mySelect.value;

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <select id="mySelect">
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="2">Orange</option>
    <option value="3">Pineapple</option>
    <option value="4">Banana</option>
  </select>


  <p>Click the button to return the value of the selected fruit.</p>

  <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>
  <p id="demo1"></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var e = document.getElementById("my_Select");
var value = e.value;
var text = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

Comment: I already used this you can check my question again

Comment: sorry I made a mistake.
Please see now